# Hide content to Googlebot

Tags: php, user-agent

If I want to hide some content on Mozilla Firefox, I use this code:

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Gecko') == FALSE) { ?>
Hide only in Mozilla
<?php } ?>
```

My question is, how to hide some content to Googlebot?

Comment: changing content for google crawlers will likely lead to your site being blacklisted.

Comment: My site dont have meta description, and i just want to hide my category and authors, because google always show my category & author in search result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect googlebot based on user agent some thing like

You can find list of User-Agents at  http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/

**For Googlebot :**

`if (strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],"Googlebot")) 
{
 // do some functionality
}`

But It's a bad idea to hide elements for google, google is smart and you could definitely get punished for this.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355

Comment: Thank you Gopal, but i just a newbie. I dont understant your code. Can you give to me a complated code, please!

Comment: if (!strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],"Googlebot")) { 
 // display your categories and authors
}. this means it will check in the user agent whether string "Googlebot" available or not. as I added '!' (not) means code with in {} will work for non Googlebot user-agents

Comment: To extend your code..

<?php if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Gecko') == FALSE) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Googlebot') == FALSE) ) { ?>
Hide in Mozilla and for Googlebot
<?php } ?>

Comment: it would be impossible for google to detect this as it is PHP and the if statement is server side all googleBot would see is the output code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put a robots.txt file on your webserver and configure it to exclude the googlebot or all search engines. a good description on how that works can be found on [www.robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

Comment: Thanks Room13 for the answere. I know about robots.txt. But i just want hide my category and authors not all page / per page. My site dont have meta description, and g**gle always show my category and author in search result.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to prevent *Googlebot* from following any links on a page of
your site, is to use the **nofollow meta tag.**

To prevent *Googlebot* from following an individual link, add:

```
rel="nofollow"
```

attribute to the link itself.